# Screencast / screen record in 4k resolution?

Tags: resolution, software-rec, screen-capture, screencasts, camtasia

I saw a few screencast on YouTube in 4k resolution.

I did a quick web search and found that there are a lot of screencasting software that record in 4k. Camtasia being one of them.

I was wondering how can I record in that resolution?

Do I need to buy a monitor that supports 4K resolution to record in 4k or will I be able to achieve it by just upgrading my graphics card?

Kindly do guide me in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: You will need a 4k monitor and a good gpu. The one suggested by @RyanIG will work. The software that is mainstream to record screens (and free) is called OBS  [Open Broadcast Software](https://obsproject.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes to screencast in 4k resolution one must have a display as well as a GPU that supports 4k.

I was unable to find a way to get 4k content with just 4k enabled graphics card.

Comment: I wonder if something like superscaling + shadowplay on an nvidia card, or its AMD equivilent would work

Answer (score 1):

You will need a high end GPU like a GTX980 Ti or a Titan X

At least 32 -64Gb of ram if you plan on rendering and recording in 4k

and a good Processor, Intel Xeon or an i7.

4K gaming is very demanding and it's quite expensive to build a rig that can support it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4xDfEOGONw

Unfortunately it's not just the GPU and Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Nvidia Graphics Card, you should be able to use GeForce experience to screen record gameplay footage at 4K 60 with customizable Bitrate. Geforce Experience did not come preinstalled on my pc but I was able to get it through a GPU driver update. It screen recorded a game running at 4.5fps at 4K without dropping the frame rate on my GTX 1050 Ti (I know it’s not for 4K but whatever). The app is also free from Nvidia.

The app also comes with other useful features like game optimization and screen recording the last 30 seconds and etc.